# Coverage files not getting created in CI

Tags: github-actions, coverage.py

This is my workflow (shortened):

```yaml
on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  tests:
    name: Run tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.7", "3.8", "3.9", "3.10"]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          python -m pip install tox tox-gh-actions
      - name: Test with tox
        run: tox
      - name: Upload coverage artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: coverage-data
          path: .coverage.*
          if-no-files-found: error
```

This is `tox.ini` (shortened):

```
[tox]
minversion = 3.24.5
envlist = py{37,38,39,310}
isolated_build = true

[testenv]
deps =
  {[testenv:coverage]deps}
commands =
  {[testenv:coverage]commands}

[testenv:coverage]
setenv =
  PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}
deps =
  coverage[toml]
  pytest
commands =
  coverage run -m pytest
```

The `.coverage` files get created locally on my Windows PC, but do not on Github Actions CI.

You can find the full files [here](https://github.com/demberto/tkinter-msgcat). SO wasn't allowing me to put it all here.